# How to set profile name in AWS CLI when using instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer

I have created an instance with instance profile associated.
I am trying to run packer on the instance without using access and secret key, hence I am using the [profile](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon#shared-credentials-file) option.

However, the packer requires a profile name, but the instance profile doesn't create a profile name and also doesn't create credentials under ~/.aws.

I can see the access and secret key associated via the AWS CLI, however it doesn't have a profile name.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-132 ~]$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************3IO2         iam-role
secret_key     ****************cFvD         iam-role
    region           ap-southeast-2             imds
```

As I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28971147/7762203), access and secret keys are rotated frequently, I am wondering how can I set the profile name to the credentials permanently, so I can refer that in packer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be a profile name as you're using an IAM role. Instead you should [natively use the IAM role](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon#iam-task-or-instance-role) instead.

> Finally, Packer will use credentials provided by the task's or instance's IAM role, if it has one.
>
> This is a preferred approach over any other when running in EC2 as you can avoid hard coding credentials. Instead these are leased on-the-fly by Packer, which reduces the chance of leakage.

Remove the references to the profile option, and it should just natively work just like the SDK / CLI functionality would.